# How do you get ASP.NET to insert a database record when a user logs in?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

All I want to do, is insert to a database the username, log in time, and IP address of a user when they log in. This would literally take a few lines of code in PHP, but after requesting help in several forums and trying many different solutions it seems to be an impossible task for ASP.

The closest I've gotten is adding this to the front aspx page (where it redirects after logging in):

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
```

The problem is I can not get it to do an insert after that to save my life. Selects into grid view? No problem. Insert data on page load? No way.

I can not believe that no one has ever encountered this before.

Other notes

- The site will not load into Visual Studio.
- I've attempted to edit the .cs files in the temp directory, but nothing seems to happen
- I'm editing the .aspx files in the webroot directory.
- I'd be more than happy to use straight C#, but I have no idea how to add to the middle of an aspx page

Comment: Are you using an ASP.NET membership provider for authentication?

Comment: I am using C#, also I did not create this application and the server is a total mess.

Comment: Also, it has been expalied to me that the server compiles the aspx files and sticks the result in a temp directory. My issue is, then why do you edit the aspx.cs files if they are only temporary?

I think I'm missing the overall idea of how ASP works as a framework, but I'm just hoping to be able to add this one function as a favor and move on. I've now spent 4 days on this with nothing but Compilation Errors to show.

Comment: Compiled code != source-code. Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723(v=vs.100).aspx). When you compile a Web application the **compiled code** is placed in the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder. This folder is a subdirectory of the location where you installed the .NET framework. Typically, the location is the following:
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\versionNumber\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Comment: The web root is at: C:\inetpub\www.dailyrecord.us and contains no .cs files.

I found another folder at C:\Temp\DailyRecord\DRWebSite that seems to contain related .cs files, editing them did not have an effect on the site.

Comment: Do you have access to the source files or just what is on the production server? How much experience have you got with ASP.net? It sounds like you only have what is on the server. Generally with ASP.net you develop on a local machine, then deployed to a server. What is deployed is not generally suitable to develop with. You need the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're working with a pre-compiled site - so, editing the code is doing nothing?

If you have complete control over the code, then it should be a simple matter to do an insert into a database in that event handler - we do that all the time. Are you using standard ADO code or trying to use some databound control or something? Just a straight up ADO call would be enough...

You know... this stuff...

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);

connection.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Came back to say what I did, I have a link to the PHP app on the ASP site, when the user clicks it they are redirected to sessionphp.aspx where it puts the session information in the database. It then redirects to a php login page with post variables. The php checks the post data and IP address then automatically creates a session and finally redirects them to the main page of the PHP app. Not totally secure, but it works well and the user is redirected so fast the don't notice how clunky the whole process is :P

Comment: Ahh yes... I have done that before. It's a somewhat secure way of creating SSO for the two sites. I thought the question was about logging, but you can do anything you want with ADO.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [ASP.NET membership provider](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/05/07/ASP.NET-2.0-Membership-and-Roles-Tutorial-Series.aspx), if you're using SQL-Server you can inherit from `SqlMembershipProvider`.

Then you could override `ValidateUser` and log if it returns `false`(or always).

```
bool isValid = base.ValidateUser(username, password);
```

You can get the ip in the following way:

```
public static void logWrongPasswordAttempt(string userName, string passWord)
{
    // Look for a proxy address first
    var IP = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    //Trim and lowercase IP if not null
    if ((IP != null))
    {
        IP = IP.ToLower().Trim();
    }
    if (IP == null || IP.Equals("unknown"))
    {
        //If IP is null use different detection method else pull the correct IP from list.
        IP = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToLower().Trim();
    }

    List<string> IPs = null;
    if (IP.IndexOf(",") > -1)
    {
        IPs = IP.Split(new[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        IPs = new List<String>() { IP };
    }

    foreach (string ip in IPs)
    {
        // insert your record into database
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1387944: As i've mentioned at the beginning of my answer. I would suggest to use an ASP.NET membership provider. You can even create a custom provider by inheriting from an existing or from the abstract `MembershipProvider` class. But it's easier to use an existent like `SqlMemberShipProvider` if your dbms is sql-server anyway. Then `base` is `SqlMemberShipProvider` and `ValidateUser` automaticaly validates the user with the given password via database. If you don't want to use ASP.NET membership, you could use above method alone to log, but you have to authenticate yourself.

Comment: You should change your SA password on the database now that you've exposed it to the world.  1) You have a string with quotes inside it so you need to escape them, I usually do `@"blah;someString=""nwested quote"";morestuff"`, 2) You shouldn't show detailed errors to remote users, instead use RemoteOnly in web.config: https://support.gearhost.com/KB/a337/remote-errors-in-aspnet.aspx

Comment: btw, instead of the funky looking `ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]` you can just use `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress`.